# Make buttons which call same event handler using standard DOM manipulations

Tags: javascript, dom-events

What am I essentially trying to do is to produce container with buttons, which have the same handler but get different arguments like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <button onclick="onclick_handler(1)">1</button>
    <button onclick="onclick_handler(2)">2</button>
    <button onclick="onclick_handler(3)">3</button>
</div>
```

Using this:

```
function onload_handler() {
    var container = document.getElementById("container");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var button = document.createElement('button');
        button.innerHTML = i;
        button.addEventListener('click', function() {
             onclick_handler(i);
        });
        container.appendChild(button);
    }
}

function onclik_handler(val) {
    console.log(val);
}
```

And when I click buttons I get 4 in my console. What am I doing wrong?

Could it also be done without usage of anonymous functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to resolve the problem created by closure, by creating a scope per iteration,

```
function(i){
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    onclick_handler(i);
  });
})(i);
```

And your full code would be,

```
function onload_handler() {
    var container = document.getElementById("container");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var button = document.createElement('button');
        button.innerHTML = i;
        (function(i){
          button.addEventListener('click', function() {
             onclick_handler(i);
          });
        })(i)
        container.appendChild(button);
    }
}

function onclik_handler(val) {
    console.log(val);
}
```